# Get group ID (GID) of a file in Mac OS X via a shell command. What is the equivalent of stat -c "%g" <filename> for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, stat

So, I want to quickly get the group ID (GID) of a file using the shell (more accurately, the GID of the owner of the file).

Somewhere in my shell script, I have the following code:

stat -c "%g" foo.txt

In every Linux I have tried, the above works perfectly.

However on Mac OS X, I get:
stat: illegal option -- c
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]

How can I get the GID of a file on MacOS X with a shell command? Preferably something that also works on Linux, but I am okay with introducing an if-else if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent on OS X is `stat -f "%g" foo.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following command:

```
ls -n my-file.txt
```

This would output:

```
-rw-r--r--  1  502  20  578  Dec 3 20:44  my-file.txt
```

Here, 502 is the user-id (uid), 20 is the group-id (gid), and 578 is the file size in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

For my Mac OS Monterey ( 12.4 ), the above didn't work. I'd to pass in the string formatting option `S` along with `g` as below
`stat -f "%Sg" foo.txt`